# Implement the hyperfactorial

Tags: code-golf, math, combinatorics

## The objective

Given the non-negative integer \$n\$, output the value of the hyperfactorial \$H(n)\$. You don't have to worry about outputs exceeding your language's integer limit.

## Background

The [hyperfactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html) is a variant of the factorial function. is defined as
$$
H(n) = 1^{1} \cdot 2^{2} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot \: \cdots \: \cdot n^{n}
$$

For example, \$H(4) = 1^{1} \cdot 2^{2} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 4^{4} = 27648\$.

## Test cases

```
n   H(n)
0   1
1   1
2   4
3   108
4   27648
5   86400000
6   4031078400000
7   3319766398771200000
8   55696437941726556979200000
```

## Rules

- The [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- As this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: I think one might be able to write a competitive 4 bit assembler (or even 8 bit assembler) answer which is a tiny LUT.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A002109

Answer (score 14):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
*)P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19LM@C/zuH2rEcNcxR07RQeNczVjPz/3wIA)

### How it works

```
*)P - Main link. Takes n on the left
 )  - Over each integer 1 ≤ i ≤ n:
*   -   Raise i to the power i
  P - Product
```

Comment: I will accept this answer since it appears to be the shortest.

Comment: @Nirvana I appreciate that. However, 8 hours is far too short to accept a winner, as it often indicates (unofficially) that the challenge is over. If I accept a winner, I usually wait a minimum of 3 days so that everyone has time to see the challenge. Additionally, we discourage accepting an answer on pure [code-golf] challenges, as we consider these challenges to be competitions *within* languages (e.g. Jelly vs Jelly, rather than Jelly vs Java), and accepting an answer contradicts that. It's entirely up to you if you'd like to follow that convention however.

Comment: Jelly will still be the winner, 3 bytes is damn short

Comment: Tied with [Gaia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236009/43319) now.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing see, and THAT is why we have the occasional "ban golflangs" thread on meta - you can say how things should be and stuff but this is reality

Answer (score 9):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
Product[n^n,{n,#}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6AoP6U0uSQ6Ly5PpzpPR7k2Vg0olplXoqDvkK7vEJSYl54abaBjEfv/PwA)

also as @att mentioned there is a built-in for this...

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 14 bytes

```
Hyperfactorial
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n27736OyILUoLTG5JL8oMzHnf0BRZl6Jgr5Dur5DUGJeemq0gY5F7P//AA)

Comment: The built-in `Hyperfactorial` is 14 bytes

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
⍳×.*⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//Ue/mw9P1tIDU/7RHbRMQXK5HfVOBAmkKJv8B)

Monadic fork train

First it evaluates range of the input, and dots the power and takes the product.

Comment: While not as nice looking, `×.*⍨⍳` would be more efficient.

Comment: @Adám nice, i wasn't aware of this use of commute

Answer (score 8):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 3 bytes

```
*†Π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/X@tRw4JzC/7/NwEA)

`†` vectorizes the operator on its left, integer arguments are implicitly cast to ranges. `*` is exponentiation and `Π` the product of a list.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7), 20 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n?n**n*f(n-1):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxDkAwFEbhV7mDobdC2ARl9RiaUiHyX0Es4tmr01m@s9nHXu5cjzuDTHMI3sB06KE1tFfISq7L4OVUIENFQ6DWUBWbpkxOcMk@57ssahxU8uLjyJI3nvyNHH4)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 28 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n<1or n**n*f(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIc8qz8Ywv0ghT0srTytNI0/XUPN/GoivkJmnUJSYl56qYalppVBQlJlXogGU19T8DwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles), 2 bytes

```
$*@^
```

Note that this problem influenced how nibbles decides to use implicit args from implicit ops. I'm currently thinking of getting rid of implicit fold since it is uncommonly used though.

```
     # implicit fold since accumulator is used
     # implicit range from 1 since there's things after an integer 
$    # first input integer
 *   # mult
  @  # accumulator from fold
   ^ # exponentiation
     # implicit $ since need another arg to ^
     # implicit $ since need another arg to ^
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 59 bytes

```
fun h(i:Double):Double=if(i<1)1.0 else Math.pow(i,i)*h(i-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxDsIwDAV/xaONwCIbQu3GykcEKVGfCHZVUnWo@u2hAqZb7u7ptcBay7PRwLjefH6UJH/2yIwuSNAzpfJOdI910NEXxhFy2INTkG/7ijCWNftEDIJRUL3IOk6wWox3U6v/piwi29Y@)

Longest submission yet, but thought I might as well give Kotlin a shot. Used the `=` format for functions to eliminate 2 brackets as well as the `return`.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice answer!

Answer (score 5):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 51 bytes

```lisp
(load library
(d H(q((N)(i N(*(pow N N)(H(dec N)))1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DccxDoAgEATA3ldsuWelnU@g4g8oFpegIJIYXn/SzTS9e9K3mDHlEJF0r6H2iRGOD@mFCs@ZJX/wGHWM5zEgshqvUODApWVsIvYD)

### Ungolfed

```lisp
(load library)            ; for *, pow, and dec

(def hyper                ; name something
  (lambda (n)             ; a lambda function that takes one parameter n
    (if n                 ; if n...   
      (*                  ; ...is non-zero, multiply...
        (pow n n)         ; ...n raised to itself...
        (hyper (dec n)))  ; by the hyperfactorial of n-1
      1)))                ; otherwise if n is zero, return 1
```

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jJz8xRSEnM6kosaiSSyNFwUOjUEPDT1OjoCg/pTS5RCM3sUBLoSC/XMOgJF8BKA6m/oOEFTwUwDwLTc3/AA) non-recursive solution

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
Πm´^ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8eGOxf/PLcg9tCUOxPr/3wIA)

```
Π       # product of
 m      # mapping across all values of
     ḣ  # 1..input
  ´^    # x to the power of x
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.factorials`, 15 bytes

```
hyper-factorial
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoZcGFspMzClWKChKLSmpLCjKzCtRsObisvifUVmQWqQLV/Ff7z8A)

Built-in.

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, <sup><s>33</s></sup> 27 bytes

```
[ [1,b] [ dup ^n ] map Π ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcvBCQIxEIXh@1bxCpCAR7UA8eJFPIUVxuyshtVJNpkIdmNFthSj3h4/3xvJaUj1eNjtt2vcSa8mkVw4Y@IkfPunsYhTHySbmPyDlJF5LiyuuR8o4l0YGDGx6rMhUWy6bgUflKqFXS7OPSyGEnES9O0V8X6hr9@Rldxk6gc)

This could have been 26 bytes, but `^` returns NaN for 0^0. Factor is the only language I know of that doesn't just return 1 for that. So I had to use `^n` instead, which is a helper word used to implement `^` that hasn't been 'fixed' yet.

- `[1,b]` A range from 1 to whatever is on top of the data stack, inclusive.
- `dup ^n` Raise an integer to itself.
- `[ ... ] map` Apply a quotation to each element of a sequence, collecting the results in a new sequence of the same length.
- `Π` Product of a sequence.

Comment: You can add [Mathematica](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvJNogziD2/38A) to that list :)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 20 bytes

```r
prod((x=1:scan())^x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq5BWmpdckpmfp5GpqVCtUJycmIciqpmpoBySWlyiUF6UWFCQWvS/oCg/RUOjwtbQCqRWQ1MzrkLzfy1XWn6RRqZCZp6CgZWppkJBUWZeiUYa0EzN/wA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 20 bytes

```hs
h 0=1
h n=n^n*h(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0PBwNaQK0MhzzYvLk8rQyNP11Dzf25iZp6CrUJuYoFvvEJBaUlwSZFPnkK0RnFGfrlChaaCtraCkoKtHZAAssCiKgoZIImaChvdaAM9PUOD2Nj//5LTchLTi//rJhcUAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic, <sup><s>19</s> <s>17</s></sup> 14 bytes

```
prod(seq(I^I,I,1,Ans+not(Ans
```

sadly `0^0` or an empty list errors, so `0` has to be turned into `1`

Answer (score 4):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 42 bytes

```
[range(.+1)]|reduce.[]as$i(1;.*pow($i;$i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8rxcdW/M/uigxLz1VQ0/bUDO2pig1pTQ5FSieWKySqWForadVkF@uoZJprZKpqfn/f7SBjqGOkY6xjomOqY6ZjrmORSwA)

Comment: You can simplify the [range]|reduce.[] to [`reduce(range(.+1))as$i`](https://tio.run/##yyr8X5SYl56qoadZU52dWmmloKejUJaYU5pqpaDxvyg1pTQ5VQOqQttQUzOxWCVNw9BaT6sgv1xDJc1aJU1T879mrUKNglKMhh7QAE0FXTsFIBNshqbSfyMDAA) to save 4 bytes]

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 51 bytes

```java
n->{var r=1;for(;n>0;)r*=Math.pow(n,n--);return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY49a8NADIZ3/woRMJwT@0jWXhzo2CF0CJ1KB9Uf6bm27tDJLib4t7uXlA7iQejl0dvhhEVXf6928I4FurjrUWyv25EqsY701iRVjyHAGS3BLQHw42dvKwiCEjE5W8MQb@oibOn6/gHI15A9ogAvJG@EPL/6hlEcQwslrFScbhMycHkwrWNl6LQ3GW/LM8qX9u5HUU5FkRluZGQCNstqHr6YBmVJgKJnbyKOcLhzt/t/CXCZgzSDdqNoHztJqzZp/QRpndImB8qh1eh9Pz@HWE9Rlv25l@Q@y/oL)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 28 bytes

```c
H(n){n=n?pow(n,n)*H(--n):1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/daoMwFL7vUxwEIWkTptV23ZzbxRj4DtMLibGTtVGMUJn46suOP5V2B5KTfD8n@QQ/CmFMRBTtVKjeqvJCFFN0HRHOFX12g94UqoFzWihCoVsB1gA0Ujf6M4EQOoeBy2DLwGPgM9j1waKSbSVFI7NJ6I5ClLjOAQ2Pex/bYe87Q80u8ZXWa9yl@Jb1ZLPi9mMbt0/vuHYWg9u7Z82@vKyBDE8WKpMt2pxgPr6ALn5kmZPrZ@jDDKwXJIDNZlRfIy4xcdIUdaST4I7VyEakofeoRHQJ/t9W1SjJiWV7GfBXsDOwdawwVcNAsyW4DEOdzHP7VW9@RX5Kj9rwi@Gn8x8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 43 bytes

```
var F=Fn.new{|n|n<1?1:n.pow(n)*F.call(n-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcpBCoAgEAXQq8zSCRpyF1G08wKdQEIoqJ@YJJGd3Va99UvBoZTLBjKDgcClJyOj16PuIP5IClwZme22KdSa36IakZbF2XmhJxMo03Sf0e3iw4qo/sxMb/kA)

Alternate:

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 44 bytes

```
Fn.new{|n|(1..n).reduce(1){|a,b|a*b.pow(b)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDsIwDAXQq3i0EfqiGwsrF@AETnAFUjFVKERVnLOH92oxHz8tNNNlXB1utYUHT4ALit2/2XiSFnpMoYeE9V05Se@DT8BZYJof1IKcgm77Z7MX1vL0jWdkXRZ2EerjDw)

Comment: wow reminds me a lot of rust

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ɾ:eΠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C9%BE%3Ae%CE%A0&inputs=4&header=&footer=)

Obligatory answer

```
ɾ              # Range
:              # Dup
e             # Power
Π            # Product
```

Answer (score 3):

## dc, 24 bytes

```
?[1+[d1-d1<xr1-d^*]dsxxp
```

#### Explanation

This is a complete program, that reads input from stdin and writes the result to stdout.

```
?                       # input
1+                      # avoid H(-1)
[                       # function x
  d1-                   # 
  d1<x                  # recurse       : n n-1 ... i+1 H(i-1)
  r1-                   #               : n n-1 ... H(i-1) i
  d^*                   #               : n n-1 ... H(i)
]dsxx                   # define and execute
p                       # output
```

#### Output

H(n) for n = 0..12

```
0
1
4
108
27648
86400000
4031078400000
3319766398771200000
55696437941726556979200000
21577941222941856209168026828800000
215779412229418562091680268288000000000000000
61564384586635053951550731889313964883968000000000000000
548914237009501581804104224704637116078267727827959808000000000000000
```

My machine takes almost 0.7 seconds to compute H(200), but it does produce the correct result:

```
114256002424540571298977792354054343003217988447353197803701128087779\
727310773544883222069862169886712875089569689613436517195625058699339\
831616247967378727547253765461789388643475674400611735920545310021028\
378006078740483920058608872101517118552137511462765664553099379243826\
960171887170750794198373595289872526218671094534622811250467573078955\
097722440499909299236803909456886903559422482755722874996888761181995\
575299415208051459908113833797191408981585936952677202993799475038316\
559629150663378834397372775965856682894873495939410259095804412984759\
376802645433107086846121910224544820403394942396165166503784543183923\
373316267239065885057694972898540625272750046246522113004186914354002\
967536413371473458112220769020094756837578527902012213205896270144393\
863599279497755781359466901673079326909202551645285985747551170700716\
842425698975536766498808553756048408306339794216494138288030784286578\
757511579359563917784149939178533514638276262178221710320662541522716\
166268310550789650887610134719729891484651131282509122835031254510412\
859215509732637002095449585308892098589802359045914197581197309643963\
042570582527203047381981490652454323893038445041694758990588984561508\
024977520153869302479414855203541538559245994267482585355022642863859\
784222422005021616964777696793772349735028255170680455712484791660880\
381133647422166704047722699070109094074510187247343055332257496929374\
982064491045838594959100552218107373079642910265887514107042314387137\
231583168255471546888411138370063211060324585902513206145493958317539\
840648935101056767774783896580016743810934173275647035655085909723344\
400585286826414068777563965071196389690941135698863589037499407785370\
931798703443963281315725441703395909623807818562899480337755459429222\
263976154559801703132418440141220192063353095047779835936440544198953\
496106173470542538936478118001519398934406367850808122800102137273226\
951723289344106737093183594520201847490204826536442751006791251960765\
409736570349501810834880546030444722460505622335562771218876927864732\
533831989277488466279926764165356648286028875357501991394907871736473\
399337480995325006099531629623628775557151039011468601336589825839738\
631718648726576082486937471392562052316112813773965598704019732181766\
979636498126699138316658703065343361486555049963171513229287190102366\
294038070909517003192684859103788524924734600167422726737999487560861\
040910125441478016464932490390352767808126453168977619717961242515337\
678589841167345358713873500430963639031923908700261694508782150681050\
006111529466925629252138641356979249757548377531461415227595617743646\
019706623647306680452085764528828628378729906162793797766057848324098\
880977726680150730390074716141211796155230858668012021940942979991319\
892197094655756666501455192326506825509530719155451676296396102560013\
841584265351485313695020472184192704099107932797640710173835532960606\
518538605516574602321430208034314359982648827905481627199797808702727\
344458806167205608568625797981988480548489292548067131307825217362115\
487277151573038609637079476077578954700658210221211043513144482137132\
113794287001433270940578127570053434695653912547579202493901871464470\
764410974150819235945558607363556467922279391141836922743541233760821\
871365085257243448039467666652724537269128483841450819722610910449669\
667767218934240840176992473839442233550613463850853485560398554469357\
611537501209062167152021399590356213475289096528949653047033419077429\
299028564676171187099901772701404490557158793484243417114875079809449\
627812693323373523747772814832161656651663374496734064538978915783865\
719064174822864696226655708942852177545994665514849721267519945794503\
019098476165255673401283399976325921222555982464845071082560857852257\
814145566478967899059920204170727945409097495154492869672134459786294\
588119159908191561922643839816897827104225462279731830827250471252105\
289727169676968836275320004859466161656331082081074381176816967370602\
357442772694553727911750007625712888624429904817070697897964886832493\
345528030314492840383966128843659735252693645758721744757267671336699\
697149807573431757428427239466529780150411631632066022100098544057533\
387989402082327607683479023952713064900546185006785478600337149539296\
663361814407606344949829339294479920368454331595871231338484805775737\
339268396124977267103545541977669058589689418363091692719790628856414\
752071432633359549389607990792617571221154257026279901828952182073374\
160861868734416746968494659933958156742463652295106500468210780119125\
220209380290875380832470409648848082808663586942813054685601333888677\
903229796350639694587698272283080314334773653111218034106708436851163\
056715554656438061557864316343565021443951504379532417965485201636186\
463813912432724675905548790267512971651098333554063940806626704854532\
678674167073399666603479497096163139406079292169446126287164855437310\
733645103657687054384245612640135453530729419221334723538721255762469\
348656691594173954864816605371367857438364854545334435452281244641153\
702780834293385080202596856941397712010881729069210455124793116543955\
764287224835926198843406678698041913931641907309743017824157088832657\
515931712589921404995250184506019056203133181617154100069201866951525\
300872664323283710970049931600220543834155799207559964184227001086729\
978318247276684554857576596547291291791522751007585853793360225113135\
450501518599762144278325251060114811491521595770223299394208499421070\
133134002376834102080109021979719187115415860089714599508435221834288\
106979134790461271826466644755668937746875390891835581995388195707703\
666919259484508094626586130500902421761233473185812236823727560637765\
353284587005782503482049179577624131003496831794473409129318251405306\
686312023625090599797707676764002997295491901065845799891148513188011\
750255365930732717166438760960930254270355434958193721008813937013342\
442685357933848612269061232591941511207731095268816549202309436856983\
863709498625968309204249579255954213842990272453525630818763597799543\
593087313268427793519216838584166922708627220843209392429847694078662\
627081045478537054881042974186251081449455396030353464966077751989172\
967094495553235926368816821576526232804884953832820814720565106292278\
677023212354425827714341638534116865568614053180685437672841412518894\
098874469347176584909301684501882789675804879960815875737873223894302\
068322229857523890186183543936935430404240034004709340156823935334504\
280773088422757352262015925135936299428100399162508993701323816640249\
317502708643002177380916843121414525377166307214659890456197078789358\
755908958395704605757659385312957851526639927217127812638621838046618\
256249655670855709886714485145533985086443137064765377391996261567764\
614649944571049532129160422595979803302687452962711606329612008212827\
794401494192040770665411078681415279435060816655175330979102977082874\
632330444354061833803759173996116082517816249241467318683953133297949\
696966800597273657946143827878859661836812064102045501830604467916228\
427069899293175548188750078304435399590540700476604483395383697312578\
097710820312329606242276447140831589400706797160881537904137892646388\
261066966454548869342350130453494223912785614903507340787315001904795\
688540272824396638149906352594040357284385938277509795452746883194274\
390009993333838096016899929412160162615538212444522338199878096100853\
638701901085648519985630176886727084180895587065782329076867465210575\
281386375663556976026065633532489743239889186305075304808560243262432\
658085969412020827902073591982408638009516334902222599715386120602437\
678310010096587347186053193158239648969456170841664624039286167247669\
514436308002065354268316000349861095951926759431651589488622884486382\
277854033455441602586071384379537383305706042265499575026224506704860\
688406915452474511683218154440889210555179680616817271305312473155544\
143262273531331795805472254371401019589348634412412286987413907792718\
329915124784729596566415082748529970796499261705982501268401723583887\
701661443797764811659857704733113125011378104100970585073283674392976\
859476816730766230843992524449084734798618995888731548845560723062966\
192859122943220390909175950182057052843622022554828023378885550828117\
382718195394157370910647482474167099695486548360631460470999045477378\
132717331452335714187924997815103638622262298849924210205241176668405\
490741524219253278664341011210099915988552406343854573062664870584245\
103886217277906440977065037168659090059763288778505082007530932618466\
494869181704099810631362022702089755491800061458537467852967380851010\
908862739733011423332473338496528317600181547938903583970178021411350\
504107353290656971578124200774189092891257270280529095290550988723728\
135603533746551804333320307013973767695324099720923379543683864817974\
710553868201698590292895333412491357784173524677821074492989035878523\
065616904294807445990638805797254482102285949882214670841897742949328\
311659987640881568459282440548451135162773664037389258355421285035420\
999699985577663763700005757941427315733197266168699581396576204803981\
473126870934075898120336661598190205939756443947057710182924789850055\
001425654550118743113257624420824183938997656885814673594734917916409\
078995498945642404630814171603046441105445059249548610322842910754951\
846627795460490833776103956049657955540015291032378840531042472594532\
860423319860149058941766354088020712438608204454072807575885575852839\
180700772630347090579280688794361068997524503617691544202365939291565\
645671286667544529026174876789733907296960576178709446195376983454472\
164584703777117244823990537583736958740841562740244004026203727555258\
450538750500484541128688250020648123312909872053878444932137569761105\
646598390520596957373979148797644934213546809772428508682350740007209\
819026797315661258929751889448192710982091237434909749464078055542925\
758110822533573122134535676028907089176208169078890508131338313078120\
366292092748543956445763451239618092200751801948183924253225759130045\
402864771211838018815605401626689028050384789832787839775255721097218\
181110343132212865937413848154233885501099705968645937079387543236067\
419341630111614913910492435024464166688710987099886511583318895948003\
248879615736644901850078099348201377864691386256283320069993735388706\
880978227943386880372348195108338420348643722382324037845214076409223\
421605406326543434017961739452074663199250414741826344527959432512472\
288051981715822955586322044373144003885900746941921709703799672502350\
065363701967267734865903791650802227123544971675955949787985267374530\
847885039570559135088894718198400171730871289918834134265582501872441\
817474408532347174649197682421484732565030830602652775869842343897079\
665618967792517232732353781319861024635289426450784800702094918520783\
421946020173070856497710123531146795959596308032645673704792463483238\
508003336793688645287713354332253474988554262325815954309909567664567\
573258648500395650173170779959337702622396455572300230300768415812431\
943010715240963679596296486831129989681871718230599580037772017117033\
315832399335703122496145800075686154721432794663618613863892627375137\
366428360989986599340414088453536386107561090367699159184439260424635\
745591597059093633912447921539583960069923796416538679234874262062410\
163002664653721804674990501848569881038943775993261621385733027297067\
083554262375476401287244101149052235300084299630703460854961311971283\
087073208822293226528612144677097325474675212863261753395272291201243\
727063158190087578787154328368369458561245784693838304278572756604546\
510952636210910525436103646773871458339800106430023155717178920396687\
520423472846663370278770127553170373437626792023727289514355087037311\
140097772419377161850139650623158006220407602434802036169803932182144\
364560440183502624140166248069772217517658503727605438952409331108997\
938796887451122008271640565975335203086775806001724195485708936422425\
137056283019622940342042757720398404950656311129102072111491775765939\
145688292407278548040314549680511643911856331584703069002009015743434\
987416878546802024548849006779822873402507748917427021579312534569977\
361861231854091421381548376451031427272315824402714317215823133557566\
630570188995812896381696487597394215612003133922998761317879400375340\
125754172678973925934340294567607771195422852830929279465841874639010\
009888808918675285586746078546918806973510720653329464320497985376475\
514652191137288767301110502250694677101081566428326927525440430403867\
468662023769524677616162779798242348230999586692878495342514713764186\
714882538090458901781712475105348027738734745293498558256040405894803\
195991677041814864565397732062450568265762161106477446853681187477778\
726005451422916487453440941705450833165526732124577290035369815857754\
177651321505099564890184890808449589507960017238091650940272579801976\
012553611294392411698525056432475991421017871033115166544672308666931\
153046458808727931683807887236625749116358879625843911889493775696035\
689596716234107636539958765668585942904085430988801703856400119630376\
274574597769512867580730016556216727676744713487993170219184593464999\
311291112749880481896882356531818314812757939997704540854301634559210\
168428005707651884236890080120885190924260622549699781701215291431456\
641474519410935152273699234442085712020314906414846783096378915749837\
313543205699498699058727247319542037049467226655708039331544604104781\
409084183109899592118979816757807977852975258979779416901404268104909\
705348928232083022795123709882664565805802427977177013536930315406074\
119798700228696233155965389441167947547520301277280800708044768115830\
471568118316963537054375894947474149197268583279951389007580911096150\
587642304998165318585620851425172746769477143145386873345481245188537\
754898143742686352644071418948819336880282491363012186422360754575220\
279448092609828602552016180377773970908025714516279864286548174974082\
714686202892658851979133054341592863444445185327463440688040605716405\
067027534367643153032569517666086981280522416245349519983986846967214\
042882273846333605336087299637431797991108127634339718858236191873607\
992145012212007858822784503266193271141131224661074334214839250271667\
726722076785306858810448052589267984702881718156816842983856068663911\
962262395537169886395290931248461646122637458717832878921862044114375\
961223925897580056403294305693475540045578718469567147106404825130645\
182596807474482717319438314466506464297165104699880281509113101964645\
644113558063277536948464800478797709703629400329162780840501627821037\
796082859331312091625314594124914131496550405427389764417029031881865\
161566844591130624668157039150013878652923170474308357677476499519615\
694247353253258416153487129434125741231110906666192911231143233291672\
330355835909139214586207813893211012425324068478627916498679629380977\
726349923696052885626801312565943741488193855513659470521916364497140\
595263059255234991151676056428157949653159230890433842121335826208388\
342905112604728437774206247314145114208160560382868989175460790477221\
890350677890961281703135082791138001520406832403763549570484116412249\
411630340091247083693144122332355091861372457253352008769217588001288\
849717267814951643081139792036726924049299132057170441936528548540420\
064033867805971560358101657671048958681419753322017701206905396234428\
135916258956179250871059395091929250943571633006872870216908850580206\
492968748602862989200240660330463405184596960622742947121148050963122\
321259337631048134291686503286606869138604813871549760164086721913518\
637749340223861847791025891443679650627984525254307030025638348279163\
760184818981923247501359438277271636232964640495952052708147067280051\
510417155618166064646769348176921156031703472238576803756454461973221\
654819493213203649089803381920320331786258749203931226197991150138418\
412665064324591666915076933446777039262089089651109035566583869738578\
597506761075170629480218974597816082666310188595749958551973619906326\
148650712257007357155244818379632436183006582758626649517236510683006\
346083500259745147176189562743231550874298895062648811402347137583548\
675098905750258174262052682531224862649985350791958712521075292922368\
595003093091774703254502960834476169407594973424845628114251412090192\
033055714360450494006595575968666327901355614408397215867467966118019\
576690302025344757113309733262077331055580267485085990493403505787838\
624566370526779488899761016359956759522270200707135958413154679827569\
258052868584822095448301696499657831845970412520110100094933597023662\
316700009222296695302631294120144631256162943881147670342787558109037\
638373998645356492446988510858843413188523534457356161957326654858590\
170373845392894491611342691003506990032562657375834824358150900255718\
212803029008165248772179611829216450388154836261406465215609533903379\
234291823957337623177899123066407939187764831440259804897780532314294\
187768806308300849997380071853436999411397630694458010440206190084920\
364271955929368660748369995712502790615902991832507744246091795838698\
522769638481677935709999820969951468648542838681273677603394509504240\
308953934844440452041183172657724693700991437857142495426882365464490\
656305106674560342135144470557427634289016433075831708395587229518538\
740345784633830858370131443824184367717767852454910547209118651010344\
170278635519515658320221573860591898378883482625668496205501948380927\
655730907380466792089697431597474868907457592287486991817027217936644\
429039036949024880832634934485778971951179199938014320341094585037431\
867897462971290143952624609863752298357851890137576299456918192514413\
801163490330448708940809800295269673370776121695018917895759267103596\
712356385972690041695981952213401668647553788833494484654483704349068\
176379519514076345587421597137517924620994702202104196503077589303867\
675313731830281021790349204147751254681000976845402199926482744440837\
651540373296876407741833859447282118791613435919658716973720823338943\
594717898120853679633629496999886962089450217817683016051641978808086\
090736723556850600235255229245277419993691387427177263341235769365551\
729834695110679831584857749889217164198358411783052421365582162149360\
307993926083432465922185547437809273782150112676800043051133743848179\
507430041789107391336645174236054478492193980551977769361095960852905\
792648589491408260015780133323805313428641785267726788361163481200596\
667926844213028421995386505994266261197953159903842353647124717058462\
606195804456403148297397645768181232545874395373205289680341525417879\
379518455846428797752945668078353519178914505729375052075208668206727\
272592661778659138782753383579531751393302026177424043932380082134112\
304097178637741662710535952129056797743416787671115007825195113544105\
800414762132647003564766945538753743418953135801326760189012574025757\
396710397610011038820702402557513848062197209126418415099387964034761\
398231093033942795839030074337011701661581636846153029980618680958260\
742308998894462132581019648670875157214719847690770798407251574511107\
814179573150171473104112574681707827850658431097893612857747330174826\
263221914068851894736118756496739125630025657215461297066696668503577\
183582733041405309694827396016703300218438917954326780070156715389166\
252811797028538773333761911582321084851330319089805968859787814026573\
646629476563087343556603423340827325523779940913099871860140934516188\
332561209093937145532655355122173625611654611354926043249724145062395\
052073403358582466376317856821760549451408367635975857240939403560193\
544160535875531196735080632931626952143747529382108053685709281128550\
909871592283732369684212053409742502659002594127711109142543712695800\
964668096317273980595863102507908763243035048734467097315273670192716\
453090615295589332917732324135882790481157233370637919417730168802570\
745512158460173430843355794887960375318350278147166774927332518782329\
275386354748592633069853120237345941910229584677639028790677553936767\
813561547451464211027958830776412462906122376937072679758250598400339\
993262606250183184159965386752505918305062458782151287361652904255522\
543747897277759806217530894994343172655413398182581681612121938496736\
246719088985499608274563513876622367779465393373781088492229210720940\
639881067172035481989280366082376941532976834093527635529401514366330\
480920065589598817482347629673178135543148398941148123840436738906568\
689721644562620605431787705716472884630393001383812923459261978914853\
520746731592548434175828751037428755037026486707839111075059327125186\
760809267843888455412978048743136553565305004514936125754311545290038\
133113476411189830181873166563424701146947953889262645190552239014423\
479186724429640510640861075472230063648938881018870060968494482689516\
470150615336695757696184691763777764571491211746536525826581200382784\
605048388142804433635261164053724449418044162892154965646897057026861\
825789232153560082382586610167238788922139435234549283511836608514919\
974792081235167878301494357826304603864897832044708820907368556324046\
004658209312689805738179663008251252674020278832364456345461955022865\
901541110979739876238776312716778351664263063148749685831874832132016\
935035662777717441736545169081531353892410317684943418619599602983211\
424184625311114459460166018052595314630063133375510973311332443179025\
430071437113318883337924946520194725946143840301669209247618491596869\
860173921931370251854462447254511938184185608158210889650209973353848\
709587977807510498484825736181853375451441884380345067688458992092705\
201032496281343674420762320800084135089658792761869184762558806726676\
722458885523590174826474588896231438620097505667947655896718595462296\
073149666204192795203339103128540827107637425053771608250143437698557\
563602741277179793953927426431484612463294041151573622436307805492181\
876291160640064431719636789472314597957573238616645867471630699310482\
878202680466808957828942443566435405022152223504211815437604019790140\
352872467602517381951971882961416597409274884152966514052697974929452\
665027793695015778955965479075442935816241693073367882618572751594589\
233332763571199270073344864323556528614492269184498420264356194305615\
857727851288186636797024506940862150561080428526864057887939002534833\
217825476912788772547258529042674975441187757934184514203802802167837\
147392045462453011001438365392835225710572890221334777983092342949532\
868689408224926079952260855610448736367597882931687183102425507238269\
350671010537707473483269683444914211617226098220802284536428111841021\
355314413825525092408785132949971412943096362996439440725692261405299\
307258200399719962027229993095100541076413611352139497423587018295295\
733263490522360083662929196544565837957602047504540075089561711238004\
034860643130645844174467891334579002129171400079540258966611530625073\
574579537699621459654573062084740258612527512591500081306982149777410\
740290148147295694078336177308080249486577913410339219097486516457786\
845544171494564298759086142864890534059376979463906901088806630448353\
636096572871854504331730452532484411175697139592881541769738473473501\
712004493344258375971665263709468683587321755927947969108354410237014\
622630703966864710147906778218511531246507803307199958593420532473567\
565338941629308172125890217096302195764174165228707151304339280199397\
308288128401592847641643775412416310732509438568791320603475823678213\
022091118173309854694279041928766771888599086244343677301891998549396\
563784328741226437673040978842688696069460803264848555813028336564909\
915911729088504504385439303693869743774004188440858489234825773966439\
034787945703214397718612107720992665600929489208194882429934865386410\
161115173865982683536124076579147099148505092826111112162726946323923\
139510572435234258930966885308790903440842746447356148569569613011866\
216181017947765400323520849488099226865879685849795232175081223157195\
558113479584013517247486158682510281822439736394004394576804296311483\
351867976357203923346203000720371078664247477194715030805264065168164\
569150139879569137943947304661266767151775830577387052301128796128178\
850612741616402622378092347975800584931763715144855238926949360664959\
901934960478488277241384228916947176273846643398938259717770068619213\
014487628266764663292361016953761364719861839113749885418576027074151\
042227017329247056848702075777200168698630056385228682662050087522766\
447910673436514156005878826955500834129864964744197436204252897718702\
140935816928099490760288979327872784783800062445180868891140814201746\
324920232428770583016061424533155666267075515886721407197157139617172\
925490167869130332346357795391916572750248424895052516323326428107724\
137758314910463829058203923431106387112309788487602414624710825158177\
964114057894343181183813244756477920394161657833992924683207226012989\
176214196381796431783415316737367036887146793201669533134930615758349\
947223575783239017366550781734221690665045190947669486016226383725404\
770500226241189927619067594575715556154029052556931773345332242188757\
583235984278742603970474190403890130765749990367903252262002072587910\
429054774362068368774173941070297008442489294012009854536258830415862\
001026233601932344280848478311160293863396081520870580210115748436524\
657593623927560968681489580983408355730739817090564200452344480956466\
381973804084046550012066308187061061100110433589729129116029838272092\
901063648710371584105178456534823033698557959547864668022626855435088\
024359991640953946734473401247145052161022214741899909693164691548573\
821785788946845900456932321418241684343132825893391173058763344836847\
561532940469059613092910143220708525884711120599623251659635879284306\
638801656363654771702535511935418881751805284684639099720239245439664\
571842387562222732097503344638539281322245536316693520241269544702385\
049026321864386637211322748517569828937467849864554760880814644586902\
817967247583917815946609090107550203264295298049898171083475299519485\
282963287445433963699470262712938411098771816976399495400566249571554\
094495292701957093458478414339743747576653696376752337387560862213437\
171824313862829623700800362750977008073325563635225466282360187411791\
004460727184883484132079024845042715007472443596920902083444577226102\
532571137758684844047433693020711502451132357889672168805441775716452\
471223267485604392625754951730382003113622464055081487391284375971238\
853510627596734712602568020285819183336971657562681282095948698659234\
622044625115938725879037169105695234784581029833751973597798676995302\
820884283310795836154247808946969995709972175704217930343337176372368\
862218152343059149076729388531979947396606020581038592064065753946089\
640553006735037214127820206440877419296330789981018521912638631997758\
154425722605472882333085781306809018684379163283706047649566390105938\
809942463192339285589573741721981180866761153351707263614777114324027\
136937248695379341939585067028628395598691094985690489914777669408583\
746705372076602176542601034547167613728331521534397507629206646312256\
534389673241695353105144035296082219501881690212574125509794054226513\
021405438270518614391742936205107159583300586830731485581286071874470\
727979146719804857783111177975437027458797939861069790512476711658674\
604230600339893922108479411334570557026813885541027537801880370343641\
023092718791324902103002359243661089565315113361994869576663697256249\
871813213413860690428249292925393115314038327834441363912113929007244\
105471054120698871274356091169876130969421130575239706338621628737248\
013101040294797899746928168358267493688407646225609161528591367536543\
750216752349842458665061074845656012652829943203210569645609847648814\
464710028370158307713272436594791806761106756447396480204361732530948\
047135168932828677349682361477634216624699993497496226478447072051536\
537255860545682337598542734838920307113252752500355434131067856495860\
013015939155932613207379195719908219623615714946387317825854512782265\
937569392814353157780475720686522817497914676681978626797926015043212\
826447031437776044826145179616020689954105388440566444703570607428452\
666825975085482722275544761731568680350317329391266355823582648567151\
947184773262263887240258693650257727510270752946231093646966589567787\
620541476932789987792695230980505405781968028822750078627313420324636\
601974910918848756407395140464009616507265266662863541465532812264494\
701633405156590660566452973010384370953314634322907040294450198353359\
957924325079183731192016465188487102068495632766765696940620843045103\
075957849189229063712905056032682667355175647119287597317113053888818\
341747269372365744795936558893311837335313287268687137649853296271832\
132369232948513470597966489726144074597206798929415298656496523421111\
438648338467916198955418864697867358689690541049939526892432203616666\
140157354244656146942523547307257405470211487674868073790307956335298\
035604188659325178691582979462715732209779303725246839056014094195154\
353820392910656204599835271073979873482650919077963655893924294796451\
071058930326741588268399079872254763237331178544518654879897999507167\
887498691051777847315585246832306484530047575270468824468839052404478\
471209601574499599308373476806751619934920860932630254791766257400546\
678194740441580832758218048544328980079529926710475069635876888842466\
467601583225867324238379637406226419707584550480244266279922404975917\
076093198953314433166768787654670557582769176583516340512714290053869\
488503951481971926825225950809407051148355971332272041694340467202263\
110935023726355678876173054870475696464256078760528321123516989048437\
905956100976188680575762923547321486475620783046279082273767387016824\
192792115286420878195296354046581539918274861338294922615905787217630\
753697407328812404074746964527035054665330473788617312281599693667903\
884726439880556302179216802454355012570038449126286996206666650775493\
528788476341408273837500438601870416699570809752085526061727790246214\
345643727730520403638924836303813927425447168031067163854295638774643\
166925696428378811144048893909874892635249403446686352691414736194313\
298767484562415849033332860270431449712286909235097808003929552365629\
010360548150077790573248056575513757799999890275575803774798799936015\
705905616634068871497563319841541352544107825662325607124684540278874\
608498624966561241559324542726007033114316454480672240712785896185764\
018459995360582270280586015978104402627028899003008502473747055638994\
967693615667231861323852556312680406367619704217960527830076328909665\
965806712800730336437160882833491675135268112563043378424238104782680\
959602102200424228996956152636857516180424517857400628028239135084923\
094773283114860671676978258922786514794732997721390398253472889571181\
542100313183931206138889694321740603908008622135736073752391733441636\
975148234408515167723600503139787211196698575465893988829247150988295\
132937089264063096302850653741709786986733436740774656976239880063657\
116155268958086159207748442275467563439789929514686396554465496658320\
223447220380884994806499212763873883811980450535445134692803972297225\
867200805366193198427695091115005764789732413669084712930690653442040\
106813786879863642703849455004180398239402073854230429039162641031954\
629435099190465441189701444312997824242458302224265488820857153390295\
433793663904480181503821987893778163121705707885184807286156520157629\
597511728693723440564167397261196843175017576158234990810817702896131\
719777996015606434124732743140927899396903532009620709667134228528325\
848706155364762181691764906498404995473573942979224307302520686325900\
288588511145953186978555460750414834235036978817588590166303626158325\
467769294871096811226986831480934663697186308993101874698672583904437\
163465158962552331778051757595797546950242290952793645521079004895039\
692767591940245446458333450596276630537891924213895070280398426097844\
530715344299379556436113658378942976207843994805006705871918214642436\
109945838548091417431928423665728188757851328090987241230795008197684\
315848649413968970776608596456806202072136369956191814042287222372420\
376209481097924531222327898301388536719301209812529374055978383161560\
402366674953377258306488393460543898212575858060374138609143943928859\
421499452693460735272584637554217829456324966124714620484172913424446\
250636641856678652492289914229876278180893702329869197654678473185792\
094874734672934868913884518473192107135666898214464737134834616023649\
053147415067806966481952994992502849916799522073929134809911363179677\
895671189148802338738965744455969389857438105112202482394405648155050\
107148182005207110004872831031995654451276551356170911494177294990239\
706406481375465466239414677940243242307424235254719725545446624971669\
702152385191708483627545184792059676994807387702668551969466174546191\
070089976167204039385542807339087642680041473305403563782932907930025\
137631116987099138156108731309442818766102387852144495815142081633981\
632881697289008544444602806582589282128339148425329485634849848220805\
882301325917949871098113905536521369117102228224267823573270306372102\
733761111537455389558353499292211244045077468444864626142113431527586\
522286466400715414584503504772063203681892773106418220004132714081774\
597491999689729300930217473244191652387960550998436458561695613745236\
001166814296581318010803425510340274430917394158798175053338323409296\
895304078316728847185492126230467648404918731759558489275204921648189\
641334613191196227133110671760170019469237970548463261174795407272273\
522594027490266679150920541151365410195788704615740727927544780544422\
598110239988012126879177000540770749825882570260436809736803340431649\
136968190510191903550704362810196734029394585868150873111624960230230\
557742069350224866922860141599641459998468635023793968673951162897119\
728086035656539953320600711628909574730519685523709373470327540705653\
335220915475511410416276072511187233012726872585473193916894040338571\
374438826193136849996054292140905498913040046174642438233669539176310\
583789607407253512180368844437606025278249024331609799279741279611616\
861322584297518411616294781785530343484052036928017813197714542874623\
893104213468783249037341094505389577141052425828443310012958430792311\
727117988346582534694572112528868607300926008059143735064550160993534\
371893959294190897252785800898998220518312815414328282874244854542483\
084144884284661147300876442953535032740155789184698983999831384346153\
983006391197340820087681150346256250121310000144506507275816653211852\
630981975984817089090736179427993067512616781166472204275999534793553\
617322021833089272400054973894297458318063353685017787841264474553106\
360829049698395091798134340765126619660886558810014489484062709914663\
708741730650944920828694430958398777612704295668727426847767255490582\
442679545627467864278473335035173682763601472415196578002079707749577\
314107135213271993728277051735738264251975836466432512732611786689972\
608699337829948196681354684107480481385484849536484464106863440975075\
994217657465056219979904595946381966476849760448223076261701459070061\
687625054331070175625148912661262855682533836542470290189307124949454\
672111611301805004282852900469603204454324036160696770568960944006915\
594827374701825793755790511037718231065384570551424914193952437022019\
147130808230140601516999108348126846206887388610494786068336045545230\
386547383991447354800219696499145798056154296637585126096623520286444\
288305461145769481278589644578052606086180987165823906712158053404792\
980245030450164180495915810341531071371713245374578291912729968835571\
659825921274987410512270834924930038942448094826206189084393728747672\
357486250170830682722765817202938882549637223733854649840690650685232\
211002887389219217763704500338914117582617774854375481599185641152046\
183882661395114967337515949838169059628528759746112017143381482333240\
207636582516552896998276786656377571917952133344673723723199179946376\
062254968796003889455221680129540086287321979565069006140531343219593\
747069127462641245536369725942802473102446619255641348424461524297528\
641759974893850890344358331952587334415026185630433554813105770680276\
206280811154949857037528958921963356897630116085109662629658178710778\
798507677725507889134611505315019012251749685690615365792458854857564\
533772662584359952011155264798453844727367592264801349010155252265810\
515246872918204705203793356728720160385276922933864379463998271968011\
571842050057502044481500963066684456034610372353292476835007171599185\
633205112254564334103161056277370091676704684362484674751703624041192\
483451798952663197567989367387817982243873922712260253289081890271484\
747615351738812175971046116046683715704512701857342532265087086607996\
935283737670167056570125886297302351164891412546399612213734288573556\
707802998705475256939453877325826737570250328135497596341563973604069\
510058749824467593715612892797143945980953495801551897876585896910826\
657340220056000137661513683486183600171373811125423027860468400737050\
207216308417605601896328260029394054079292835908268096879154275973758\
803537767265303505542897864749285971624839089144357359776006475483809\
144785869118854493414954429886053110057911071312486249141267331932731\
443170671560086590341048521718826157724599080397854324398250330127048\
599828584475615760524773238222102476324281852003060478889467087936064\
942127015543352629999555455572774241802799902310803374356753670810717\
627142023717059360295954738858332133152053518410378971332898862617963\
385643221635046420724460061022318008822037969715733460287810128018162\
609928288493671713129317148472599626406209968454082954389237826444459\
758905973724812897657188701627543464370788843117544465505781860719350\
587987395303959379133404503898926022219829986363314693902502804136730\
055576160428616527247857010585845882973679162782760983001119225850793\
470860387219780160062333082975943454952693122775459243261504221260853\
490483200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
00000000000000000000000000
```

Larger values work fine, but exceed the maximum answer size allowed here.

Comment: I followed the advice in the question not to worry about outputs exceeding the language's integer limit.  `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <strike>40</strike> 38 bytes (supporting Big Integers)

```scala
1.to(_).map(x=>BigInt(x)pow x).product
```

Provides exact results up to crazy large numbers with several billions of digits, namely up to `Hyperfactorial(2^31-1)`.

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @user.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcyxDoIwFEbhnaf4x3aQwGqERAeDT2FqKaYGe2/KRWsMz14JbiffcCZrRpPp9nBW0H3YxbOxQtGbES6JC/2EIzO@BfBabZjDHpcgaFqc/H2rXJdC6qrLp2GVmvbvKmmmN5IuOVI/W8nAQBHK47BDDSHUVaW3M8DRBxmDWv/Ka73aUiz5Bw)

Comment: Nice, you can do `BigInt(x)pow x` to save a couple bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
⟦gjz^ᵐ×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZelZVXEPt044PP3/f4v/UQA)

#### Explanation

```
⟦            Range: [0, …, Input]
 g           Nest in a list: [[0, …, Input]]
  j          Juxtapose: [[0, …, Input], [0, …, Input]]
   z         Zip: [[0, 0], …, [Input, Input]]
    ^ᵐ       Map power: [1, …, Input^Input]
      ×      Multiply: 1 × … × Input^Input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 6 bytes

```
*/&!1+
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxtj01ugzAQhfdzCqpUVdKK+BcbsKJue4coUlwwAQUwBVciitKz105TNYvOYt43b2Yxr8qf0Xm+LB7IC4DLz4/b09eYV1EUzWpvj2q5r3TTqlmd1LjaXfzNFiuy80J+hCoehCmC0wBcUSn4FROVCo5DhUkojhnBMv2zpGKMZFIIlqVSEnpbAILauWHKESpsaQ62rdaT08XRzEWt+4NZF7ZDH59mco3tJ0RZkgmOmm5oTWd6F7vaxPVpMGOlC2fHRrevgz6YDX1y+n3T2bKpGlOWZioW3oidHQB6H/lt2a8AeyBArp36zoEFxilwr9dwkHj6zQYiHN1HA+mdf5JB6v0kEf5ZJjNOJBVhktlt/Q14emba)

- `!1+` generate `0..x` (e.g., with an input of `4`, generate `0 1 2 3 4`)
- `&` take `n` copies of each `n`, e.g. zero copies of `0`, one copy of `1`, two copies of `2`, etc.)
- `*/` calculate (and implicitly return) the product

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RD*p
```

##### Explanation

```python
RD*p  # Implicit input            6
R     # Push the one-range        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  *   # Each to the power of...
 D    # ...itself                 [1, 4, 27, 256, 3125, 46656]
   p  # Product of the list       4031078400000
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [BLC](https://tromp.github.io/cl/Binary_lambda_calculus.html), 8 bytes (61 bit)

```
0000010101110000001011010011100000010111101100111010001100010
```

Works for Church encoded numerals with `1=i`. The code is derived from the common `fac` function. Degolfed to [bruijn](https://bruijn.marvinborner.de):

```
fac [[1 [[id (1 [[2 1 (1 0)]])]] [1] [0]]]
    id 0

hyperfac [[1 [[exp (1 [[2 1 (1 0)]])]] [1] [0]]]
    exp (0 0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LDmP
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxyU34P9/EwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9xbJKfvZLCo7ZJCkr2fv99XHID/uv8BwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L     # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
      # (note: input 0 will create the list [1,0])
 D    # Duplicate this list
  m   # Take the exponent of the two lists at the same positions
   P  # Take the product of this list
      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
:t^p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36okruD/fxMA)

First MATL answer!

Uses the same range-dup-power-product

Comment: _First MATL answer_ and a very nice one!

Comment: @LuisMendo thank you! MATL is a quite nice golfing language

Comment: It looks like some kind of emoticon, but I can't figure out what's happening with the eyes...

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org), 33 bytes

```
for ((a=1;n++<$1;a*=n**n)):
<<<$a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3FdPyixQ0NBJtDa3ztLVtVAytE7Vs87S08jQ1rbhsbGxUEiEKoeoXRxvHQpkA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 17 bytes

```
{[*] [\R*] 1..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OlorViE6JghIGurpqcTX/i9OrFRQUolXsLVTqE5TAIooKaTlFynEGRr8BwA)

- `1 .. $_` is the sequence of numbers from 1 to the input argument.
- `[\R*]` is the "triangular reduction" (scan) of those numbers with the `R`eversed (and thus right-associative) multiplication operator, producing this list: ,  × (-1),  × (-1) × (-2), ...,  × (-1) × (-2) × ... × 1.
- `[*]` is the product of those numbers, which contains  factors of , -1 factors of -1, etc, as required.

If the input argument is zero, `1 .. $_` is an empty range, `[\R*]` applied to that range produces an empty list, and `[*]` applied to that list returns the multiplicative identity element 1.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.8 (pre-release), 59 bytes

```python
from math import*
lambda n:prod(i**i for i in range(1,n+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7DoAgDADQ3VN0BHQhLsbb1CDSxH7SsHj6@p59c6jsh3lEd2VgnAOITX2W5UW@GoKc5toSlULQ1YGABBzluVPdZK05R/w)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 13 bytes

(TI-84+ only, for `randIntNoRep(`)

```
max(1,randIntNoRep(1,Ans
prod(Ans^Ans
```

Takes input as the last expression entered, like so:

```
0:prgmH
               1
2:prgmH
               4
4:prgmH
           27648
5:prgmH
        86400000
```

NB: TI-BASIC is a tokenized language; that means the textual representation of bytes can be multiple characters. In fact, e.g., `randIntNoRep(` is a single character that cannot be edited as one might edit an ASCII string. This program is represented by the following hex bytes (if I translated it right):

```
19 31 2B EF 35 31 2B 72 3F B7 72 F0 72
```

Based off of [this site](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens). All tokens are one byte, with the exception of `randIntNoRep(`, which is represented with two bytes, `EF 35`. `3F` represents the newline.

### Explanation

`randIntNoRep(1,Ans` returns a range of numbers from `1` to `Ans`. This is, as far as I can tell, the shortest way to generate a range. This occupies 5 bytes. For `Ans = 0`, we get either `{0, 1}` or `{1, 0}` depending on the RNG. Since TI-BASIC errors out when trying to compute \$0^0\$, we need to remove the zeroes by taking the max of each element with `1` (`max(1,`. Even though we compute `1^1` twice for `Ans = 0`, this does not affect the overall product.

Next, we simply compute the hyperfactorial factors as `Ans^Ans`, raising the list to the power of itself. After, we take the `prod(` of this list, returning a single number.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 18 bytes

```
n->prod(i=1,n,i^i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P0/XrqAoP0Uj09ZQJ08nMy5T839iQUFOpUaegq6dQkFRZl4JkKkE4igppGnkaWrqRBvo6RkaxGr@BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>57</s> 45 bytes

@alephalpha gr8 m8 8 outta 8 (they use fold/reduce with a <s>clojure</s> closure instead of recursion to avoid function boilerplate)

```rust
|n:i128|(1..n).fold(1,|p,i|i.pow(i as u32)*p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxLDoIwEIb3nOKX1YxpGosbosG11yDRhklwaKDEBe3ZK7j@HvO6xOIVn16UGFsFjO@IAV1JehPXtImctcrWT@OLnEnBSBIbpi8J@gXrteFz4HLfSz/NEIjiYm3XHvQY/KdAmEXjqCeqn7RlRvfAlmsDMRhImHcpV7n8AA)

oeuf

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYxLDoIwEIb3nOKX1YxpGsENkdS11yDRhklwaKDEBe3Zq7j@Hsu2xuIV70GUGHsFTK@IEa4kvUnTdokaa5Wtn6cnNSYFI0lsmD8kGFZs15bPgQvQ@3mBQBQXa113wKP/P4GwiMZJT1Q/aM8Md8eeawMxGEmYf1KucvkC "Rust – Try It Online")

Comment: hacks bruh ill change

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>47</s> 41 bytes

**new code**

```
z=lambda k,a=1: z(k-1,a*k**k) if k else a
```

**old code (for python 3.8)**

```
lambda k,a=1:[a:=a*i**i for i in range(k+1)][k]
```

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8o2JzE3KSVRIVsn0dbQSqFKI1vXUCdRK1tLK1tTITNNIVshNac4VSHx/39jAA)

**Explanation:**
<s>Looping through and getting each element, we assign and insert with the walrus operator (I love this thing haha), and return the last element (Which, here, is k saving one more byte instead of using -1!). I am also making use of the default value for the lambda to assign 1 to a, since I can't assign it inside the lambda. Note that i lose 2 bytes in range(k+1) since the range doesnt go to the last number, but I don't see a way around it.</s>

Getting rid of both the walrus (rip) and the range (yes!), it is done with a recursive lambda, saving a whole 6 bytes! We multiply the values and store the result, which we send to the next iteration of the code until k = 1, when we can just ignore and return a since 1^1*a = a.

Comment: Gotta remove that whitespace! Also short-circuit operations ended up 1 char shorter: [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8o2JzE3KSVRIVsn0dbQKlshMS9FoUojW9dQJ1ErW0srWzO/SCHxf0FRZl6JRpWGsabmfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 26 bytes

```
:+&1|:*|:*&->r{r**r}|:/&:*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9ItTar8n2b730pbzbDGSguI1HTtiqqLtLSKamus9NWstP4XlJYUK6RpWehp/QcA)

I want to remove the inner lambda, but `~:**` doesn't seem to work in its place. Might be a bug or I'm missing some argument error.

Answer (score 2):

## BQN, 10 bytes SBCS

```
{×´⋆˜1+↕}
```

[Try it!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkHvDl8K04ouGy5wxK+KGlfCdlal9CkbCqOKGlTk=)

##### Explanation

````
{×´⋆˜1+↕}

{        }   # Anonymous function / block
       ↕    # 0..
     1+      # To 1...
   ⋆˜        # Raise to the power over itself (1*1,2*2,3*3...*)
 ×´          # Fold using ×
```
````

Comment: tacit: `×´·⋆˜1+↕`

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ƛe;Π
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGm2U7zqAiLCIiLCI0Il0=)

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGm2U7zqAiLCIiLCI0Il0=) because both n's are taken implicitly

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 2.2, 57 bytes

In an unexpected twist, I'm putting the old version of Swift nobody uses anymore as my main answer.

```swift
func h(x:Double)->Double{return x==0 ? 1:pow(x,x)*h(x-1)}
```

### Swift >=3.0, 77 bytes

In Swift 3, `Foundation/Foundation.h` is no longer exposed by default, and you have to explicitly `import Foundation`:

```swift
import Foundation
func h(_ x:Double)->Double{return x==0 ? 1:pow(x,x)*h(x-1)}
```

### Swift >=5.1, 70 bytes

In Swift 5.1, the `return` keyword becomes optional:

```swift
import Foundation
func h(_ x:Double)->Double{x==0 ? 1:pow(x,x)*h(x-1)}
```

TIO doesn't support all these Swift versions, but I found this website which does: [SwiftFiddle](https://swiftfiddle.com/wu5os7ieajamhafhq5oaa3pnfq).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:not(n+1)or n**n*f(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcFBCoMwEAXQvaf4uEqCAYNdFKHeJcWMDthvSN2IePa07@XzWHcOz1xqldcWP@85giOdoxNDH6wKOPVp@yaEKnuBQokSuSQTusdgxwZ/uSgPI@2lN/yES4zau7U1/AA)

Answer (score 2):

### PHP 5.6 (50 chars)

Given *$argv[1]* as a command line argument :

```php
$r=($n=$argv[1])**$n;for(;$n--;)$r*=$n**$n;echo$r;
```

### PHP 5.6 (42 chars)

To get the answer as a variable, the function *a($input)* return the answer recursively :

```php
function a($n){return$n?$n**$n*a($n-1):1;}
```

### PHP 7 (38 chars)

The function **$_ENV** is like it's PHP5.6 equivalent function.

```php
$_ENV=fn($n)=>$n?$n**$n*$_ENV($n-1):1;
```

**Note** : The **$_ENV** overwriting is a bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 19 bytes

```
f(k)=∏_{n=1}^kn^n
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9rxlyxdodd)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/26ifndqevq)

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$4\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 3.292 bytes

```
r^ua
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJyXnVhIiwiNCJd)

Beats osabie and Vyxal, still longer than Jelly tho.

```
r^ua
   a # Range [1, n]
 ^u  # Exponentiate by self
r    # Product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
ＩΠＥ⊕ＮＸιι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcY7DoAgDADQqzCWBDc3RycHDVdAaCIJv9Six6/4pucvR766JGIpFobV3QyWauieYXcNtuIJMxbGMN46Hz2fSKC1Uba@Y9GoqH@LyCzTkz4) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    Ｎ       Input `n` as a number
   ⊕        Incremented
  Ｅ         Map over implicit range
      ι     Current value
     Ｘ      Raised to power
       ι    Current value
 Π          Product
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>17</s></sup> 16 bytes

```julia
!n=n<0||!~-n*n^n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHPNs/GoKZGsU43TysvLu@/g15BUWZeSU6ehmJSZrqGgZWhgabmfwA)

-1 byte thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper) - I always forget about `~-n`

Comment: 16 bytes: `!n=n<0||!~-n*n^n`

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╒_m#ε*1╙
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1EnxucrntmoZPpo68/9/Ay5DLiMuYy4TLlMuMy5zLgsA)

**Explanation:**

```python
╒         # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 _        # Duplicate it
  m#      # Take the exponent of the two lists at the same positions
    ε*    # Reduce this list by multiplication
      1╙  # Leave the max of this value and 1 (for edge case input=0)
          # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
1ri,{)_#*}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/37AoU6daM15Zq1b1/38TAA)

#### How it works

```
1             e# Push 1
 ri           e# Read input and intepret as an integer, n
   ,          e# Range. Gives [0 1 2 -... n-1] 
    {    }%   e# For each k in the range
     )        e# Add 1
      _       e# Duplicate
       #      e# Power
        *     e# Product
              e# Implicit display
```

Comment: Also `ri),_]ze~:*`

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{n<1?1:n**n*f[n-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vOs/G0N7QKk9LK08rLTpP1zC29n@BQlq0aex/AA)

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õ_pZÃ×
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9V9wWsPX&input=NQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 51 bytes

```powershell
param($n)iex((1..$n|%{[math]::pow($_,$_)})-join'*')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPMzO1QkPDUE9PJa9GtTo6N7EkI9bKqiC/XEMlXkclXrNWUzcrPzNPXUtd8////yYA)

It is rare to see Powershell answers without spaces

Comment: [Try it online?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NQT09JJbEovVipRrVaRyVeSyW@VlM3Kz8zT11LvSYzteL///8mAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 43 bytes

```scala
1.to(_)./:(1)((a,n)=>a*math.pow(n,n).toInt)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mdChCinMRYWI9AK0nueGCg)

For comparison, the [recursive solution](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6CQ1lczNQ2uMLUd7Tx8Ehw) is 56 bytes:

```scala
def f(n:Int):Int=if(n>0)math.pow(n,n).toInt*f(n-1)else 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <s>104</s> 86 bytes

```clj
(defn h[n](->>(rest(range(inc n)))(map #(repeat %1 %1))(map #(apply *' %))(apply *')))
```

[Try this version online!](https://tio.run/##PYtLCoAwDAWvEpBiKrioB/Ai4qLU@ENjiLrw9DUbhbeZGV7ajvVWyhkHGhnmjnus2xaVzgs18kS4cAL23uMeBQorQvECF2y/jCLbA1UJztQH9skoyoAzhMbgBQ)

Cut it down to 86 bytes by using the thread-after macro.

Un-golfed:

```clj
(defn hyperfactorial [n]
  (->> (rest (range (inc n)))
         (map #(repeat %1 %1))
           (map #(apply *' %))
             (apply *')))
```

Previous 104 byte answer:

```clj
(defn h[n](let[p(fn[c](apply *' c))m(rest(range(inc n)))f(map #(repeat %1 %1)m)q(map p f)](apply *' q)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxDsIwEAS/shKKuEuXgtdYKSxzToLs42JMwesdExqkrXZGE9Lz8S7SGt0lKlanMyWpziiqCzN5s/TBeEVgzlTkVal4XYQ2DVBmjpS94dKRia8Ypj7OvJ@3IfJfY@9@IyubVpx8xa@G25cc)

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn hyperfactorial [n]
  (let [ pow      (fn [c] (apply *' c))
         nums     (rest (range (inc n)))  ; '(1 2 3 ... n)
         factors  (map #(repeat %1 %1) nums)
         powers   (map pow factors) ]
     (apply *' powers)))
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited a TIO link into your answer, hope you don't mind. [Here's](https://tio.run/##RYuxCoAwDER3vyIgQuLm4NeIQ2lTW9FYQvv91ergccvj3tnj2otyRcceQkUvi6yo7IplGPE0CfoflRObDMP0lAjVyMYYxYJQS6Wuw6RRMrzPAJ8Ccxtv) a 62 byte alternative.

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYkxCoAwEAS/suVGELSw9CViEczFKHqGQ98fk6mGme16zs@kFAaJirToyiNyxgB1IzuahG8TNMniX2jtjol9tdE1CrMd@oK3z0iged0FUzs/) using recursion, actually.

Comment: @user should probably post that as a separate answer - read comments on latest edit

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
Y\,a$*yEy
```

Takes input via command-line argument. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, here's a 10-byte equivalent in Pip Classic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/MkYnUUWrUkur8v///6YA)

#### Explanation

```
 \,a       Inclusive range from 1 to command-line arg
Y          Yank that into y
      yEy  y to the power of y
    $*     Fold on multiplication
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) -F, <s>42</s> 39 bytes

```php
for($r=1;$argn-$n++;)$r*=$n**$n;echo$r;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFSKbA2tVRKL0vN0VfK0ta01VYq0bFXytLRU8qxTkzPyVYqs//83@ZdfUJKZn1f8X9cNAA)

No PHP yet, well this is The Answer! Unfortunately I had to resort to incrementing first, because of a weird operator precedence when using `$n**$n--` (`$n` should decrement after the exponentiation if I RTM correctly, but actually it decrements first)

EDIT: nice improvement from Hydrazer, -3 bytes with a way to avoid using `$n` twice in the loop declaration

Comment: incrementing with $n is shorter [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFSKbA2tVRKL0vN0VfK0ta01VYq0bFXytLRU8qxTkzPyVYqs//@3@JdfUJKZn1f8X9cNAA)

Comment: @Hydrazer nice one! thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 14 bytes

```
Prod@{1:_^1:_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@z@gKD/FodrQKj4OiGv/@6WmphRHqxQUJKfHcgUUZeaVhKQWlzgnFqcWR6fpKBhYWcT@BwA) Composes the `Prod`uct function with a function which computes `k^k` for `k in 1..n`.

Slightly more elegant, 15 bytes: `` Prod@{_^_}@1&`: ``

Less characters, more bytes (13ch/15b): `Prod«1:_^1:_»`, or the equivalent 15b  program `Prod<~1:_^1:_~>`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 51 bytes

```java
double a(int i){return i<1?1:Math.pow(i,i)*a(i-1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU49D4IwEN39FRemVgRlFY2rC5OjcahS9RBb0h4aY/jteBVjeEMvd@@jr1IPlVTlrT/VynsoFBp4T4DRtMcaT@BJEY@HxRLuzIodOTSX/QGUu3j5EwcY/fz6hcy/t24yzhmYkXw@B9KeOOt/OlsHAg0BwhoWOY8VZGHG8dgZsHt50vfUtpQ23IdqI6KtiCBmUwyR5ICwKIHyV2eoNLx9abmVDnT4Tb6dptYZwFW2yZaFomva2KfAGcopa5JM5l3f9R8)

returning a double saves bytes as you don't have the cast the Math.pow

Same byte-count as the other java answer but using recursion.

Answer (score 1):

## [O](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/link/W1tqLDtde25uXn1kXSo=/NA==), 14 bytes

```
[[j,;]{nn^}d]*
```

[Try it online!](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/link/W1tqLDtde25uXn1kXSo=/NA==)

```
[                 # Open the array
 [j,;]            # Input range 1..n
      {nn^}       # Push a block to power by self
           d]     # Apply n close
             *    # Product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 27 bytes

*26 bytes for code; +1 byte for -p switch*

```perl
$.*=$_**$_ for 1..$_;$_=$.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FT8tWJV5LSyVeIS2/SMFQT08l3lol3lZF7/9/k3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Ungolfed (but somehow not any more readable):

```perl
for (1..$_) {
    # The built-in variable $. ($INPUT_LINE_NUMBER) defaults to 1
    $. *= $_ ** $_
}
$_ = $.
```

Comment: i think this should be 26 bytes as mentioned here https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/104014

Comment: Most of my answers end up being in Perl so this would definitely benefit me. However, [the](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8408/how-to-score-adding-a-perl-library-on-the-command-line) [general](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4776/how-do-we-count-compiler-interpreter-flags) [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions) right now seems to be "add the byte count of interpreter flags other than -e". :(

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://www.raku.org/), 26 bytes

```perl
{[*] (0..*Z**0..*)[1..$_]}
```

```perl
      0..*                  # range from 0 to infinity
      0..*Z**0..*           # zip with exponent
     (0..*Z**0..*)[1..$_]   # slice from range 1 to default variable (var passed to function) inclusive
 [*] (0..*Z**0..*)[1..$_]   # reduce on multiplication
{[*] (0..*Z**0..*)[1..$_]}  # block
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoOahYPu/OlorVkHDQE9PK0pLC0RpRhvq6anEx9b@L06sVFDy0FCJ11SwtVOo1lPzqFVSSMsvUgAqs/gPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 46 bytes

(Only works up to `n = 5`, however.)

```fs
let rec h=function 0->1|n->(pown n n)*(h(n-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Pye1RKEoNVkhwzatNC@5JDM/T8FA186wJk/XTqMgvzxPAQg1tTQyNPJ0DTU1/0cb6OmZxnLV2Cn4ZBaX6OUmFihkwHmZJalFGkBjFDIVdO0UCooy80rS8hSUVB2VFDI1/wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 40 bytes

```
func[n][a: 1 repeat i n[a: i ** i * a]a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYo7DsAgDMV2TvFmpn4XjtE1yhBBUFlShOj5afFgyZKbpnFpIkYOI78WyZgkYEXTqtJRYLMLvJ@CsPDIT1OJNwy0/OuGHQdOJoef2op1ZJjj8QE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
?ɾƛ:e;Π
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI/yb7GmzplO86gIiwiIiwiOCJd)

Will add an explanation soon.

Comment: This can be `ɾ:eΠ` for 4 bytes - input is implicitly taken if there's nothing on the stack and `e` vectorises (applies to each item in each list) by default

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 33 bytes

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(A1),PRODUCT(x^x))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJng7vzofJrxvXIkJk?e=oLS50X)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) + [`mpmath`](https://mpmath.org/), 28 bytes

```
from mpmath import*
hyperfac
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhZ70orycxVyC3ITSzIUMnML8otKtLgyKgtSi9ISkyFKbloVFGXmlWhoRecVlxRpwCQ1KjR1jA0MNNPyixQqFDLzFIoS89JTNQwNNGN1ilMLbJVi8pQ0ISbALAMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 30 bytes

```
;=p=w 1;=qP;W<w q=p*p^=w+wTwOp
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PXA9dyAxOz1xUDtXPHcgcT1wKnBePXcrd1R3T3AiLCI0Il0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2.0-alpha), 27 bytes

```
;;=i^=n+0PnW=n-nT=i*i^n nOi
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/v2#WyI7Oz1pXj1uKzBQblc9bi1uVD1pKmlebiBuT2kiLCI1Il0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>29</s> 22 bytes

```arturo
$=>[∏map..1&'x->x^x]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?Odvc4a)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 11 bytes

```
[:*/1^~@+i.
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxOtpKS98wrs5BO1MPIrJRkys1OSNfIU3NTqHCSiFTzxIivmABhAYA)

```
[:*/1^~@+i.
[:          NB. enforce f (g x)
  */        NB. product reduce
         i. NB. range 0..x-1
    1   +   NB. add one
       @    NB. then
     ^~     NB. raise each item to itself
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 15 bytes

```
+/*/'{x#x}'1+!:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs9LW19JXr65QrqhVN9RWtOLiSos2iQUARp0Fyg==)

Another quick answer.

Explanations:

```
+/*/'{x#x}'1+!:  Main function. Takes implicit input with :
             !   Range from [0..input-1]
           1+    + 1 to turn it into [1..input]
          '      For each number...
     {   }       Execute a function that...
        x        Takes the number as implicit variable x
      x#         And duplicate them x amount of times
    '            For each of the lists inside...
  */             Fold and multiply them
+/               Sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 42 bytes

```
1$01.11-1<
>:>:?v~:?^~l1=?n*a1.
1-^  >$:}$
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/31DFwFDP0FDX0IbLzsrOyr6szso@ri7H0NY@TyvRUI/LUDdOQcFOxapW5f///7plJgA)

**Explanation**

Initializes product as **1** to handle the **n=0** special case.
Loops over **x** from **n** down to **1** and puts **x** copies of **x** on the stack.
Ex: **n=3** results in `3,3,3,2,2,1`
Then takes the product of all numbers on the stack to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 38 bytes

```lua
a=1 for i=1,...do a=a*i^i end print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/0dZQIS2/SCHT1lBHT08vJV8h0TZRKzMuUyE1L0WhoCgzr0QjUfP///8mAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 7 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
/×ⁿ.+1⇡
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=SCDihpAgL8OX4oG_Lisx4oehCgpIIDAKSCAxCkggMgpIIDMKSCA0CkggNQ==)

```
/×ⁿ.+1⇡
    +1⇡  # 1..n
   .     # duplicate
  ⁿ      # power
/×       # product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 40 bytes

```rust
|n|(1u32..=n).map(|n|n.pow(n)).product()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jY5NCsIwEIX3c4qxq4nU1B8QsRRce4uiBgrtNMQEW9KcxE0Xeqjexkg9gKsH7-fjPV_G3e04nRRjU1ZMwtc3iwoLyJYw8EAbt9tKWbCQTakpOix1-yAWQmrTXt3FkoBl9nZWrQ4T_Tv59c85AKjWYIcV41rKPXr4PuiPGClYoKJO5ICoTcW25gUlinwQMfEhSbFLsY95gDATx3HWDw)

Staightforward functional approach. Follows the rules for type inference. As the program takes and returns a u32, only calls up to H(5) are supported. This is because {integer}::pow takes a u32, and casting would cost five bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [5 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

Uses the slightly older online version

```
O«▒¹Ù
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=KntefVx+&input=MQoyCjMKNAo1CjYKNwo4Cjk=&flags=)

## Explained

Unpacked: `*{^}\~`

```
         _    Implied variable, initialized to input
        ~    Range 1..
   *…\  fold with multiplication after mapping
  {   block with key of _, initialized to current number
 ^  raise _ to the power of _
} end block
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Assembly (NASM, 32-bit, Linux)](https://www.nasm.us/), 85 bytes

```
H:mov ebx,eax
or ax,0
mov ax,1
je z
n:mov ecx,ebx
x:mul ebx
loop x
dec bx
jnz n
z:ret
```

[Try it online!](https://jdoodle.com/ia/hIl)

The argument to the `H` function is passed in the `eax` register. The result is also in the `eax` register. The input has to be lower than 65,536.

Answer (score 0):

## [Cognate](https://cognate-lang.github.io), 36 bytes

```
(Let N;For Range 1 + 1 N(* ^ Twin)1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708OT89L7EkdcEiE-ulpSVpuhY3VTR8UksU_Kzd8osUghLz0lMVDBW0gdhPQ0shTiGkPDNP01ATonaltUu-dUBRZl4JhL9gAYQGAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 bytes

```
řṖΠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6MyHO6edW/D/vwkA)

```
ř            implicit input (n); push [1,2,3,...,n]
 Ṗ           raise each element to the power of itself
  Π          take the product of all of them; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), 35 bytes

**Without using NATIVE python module or syntax**

Golfed vesrion. [Run it on SageMathCell!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs81JzE1KSVTIsyooyk_RyIzLVEjLL1LIVMjMizbU08uL1eTlAgnkAQUUog309AwNYq14uRSAoKAoM69EI09HQUnXTklHIU0jT1MTAORDFm4=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

```
f=lambda n:prod(i^i for i in[1..n])
```